# Bootstrap / jQuery UI popovers for raphael.js graphics

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, raphael, popover

I've got some popovers which I'd like to trigger 'on hover' of some elements of a raphael.js graphic, but I can't seem to get them to work (using jQuery UI and Bootstrap).

I'm calling popovers on the site by referencing a specified class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-popover').popover();
});
```

Then I can trigger popovers by adding the relevant attributes to an HTML tag: `class="show-popover"`, `rel="popover"`, `data-trigger="hover"`, etc.

I've also got some embedded raphael.js SVG graphics on the site. I can't seem to get the popovers to appear for elements (paths, text, etc.) of the raphael.js graphic after I've added the same attributes mentioned above.

Say I add a square to my graphic; I can then add the required popover attributes to the square in raphael.js like so:

```
square.node.setAttribute('class', 'show-popover');
square.node.setAttribute('rel', 'popover');
square.node.setAttribute('data-trigger', 'hover');
square.node.setAttribute('data-original-title', 'Popover title');
square.node.setAttribute('data-content', 'Main popover text here...');
```

I can see that the attributes are being added to the SVG with Firebug, but the popover isn't appearing on hover.

Is it possible to trigger popovers for hovering over elements of a raphael.js graphic?

[Edit] See example http://jsfiddle.net/cQGQT/

Comment: Possible related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180963/how-to-call-raphael-methods-on-jquery-objects

Comment: I've got other parts of the graphic which work when clicked (similar to that link), I just can't get the popovers working using the method mentioned above. Using firebug I can see that the normal attributes for the popovers are present in the raphael.js graphic elements, but the popover isn't displaying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap appends the popover element as a sibling of the triggering element. In this case, it is adding the popover as a child of the SVG node. Since `div` tags are not renderable inside an SVG node, nothing shows up. To get around this, I appended a `div` to the `body` to act as a holder for the popover, and positioned and toggled it via the DOM mouse events for `circle` SVG elements.

Here is the idea:

```
// ps is absolutely positioned div in body
ph.popover({
  trigger: 'manual',
  title: 'Popover Title',
  content: 'Popover Content',
  animation: false
});

$('circle').on('mouseover', function(evt){
  var targ = $(evt.target),
  off = targ.offset(),
  r = parseInt(targ.attr('r')); 
  ph[0].style.left = (off.left + r*2) + 'px';
  ph[0].style.top = (off.top + r) + 'px';
  ph.popover('show');
}).on('mouseout', function(evt){
  ph.popover('hide');  
});
```

and the full fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BzJCq/2/

I am not sure that this is the best approach, but I think its the right direction. You can try to use the 'selector' option in the popover settings, but I find it a little trickier to place the popover that way.

[EDIT - to address swapping title/content]

If you want to swap the content of the popover based on the which node is triggering it, you can do something like:

```
// add different popover data to circles
circle.node.setAttribute('pop-title', 'Red Circle');
circle.node.setAttribute('pop-content', 'Content for the red one');

circle2.node.setAttribute('pop-title', 'Green Circle');
circle2.node.setAttribute('pop-content', 'Content for the green one');
```

And then in the triggering logic, update the pop-over element's data attributes like so:

```
// ph is the element holding the popover
ph.attr('data-original-title', targ.attr('pop-title'));
ph.attr('data-content', targ.attr('pop-content'));
```

I updated my fiddle link above.

Comment: Oh and if you are interested in the 'selector' option, look here at this guy's fiddle. it explains it way better then the docs. http://jsfiddle.net/KPeKS/4/

Comment: This seems to work well and I think I can see the problem. The problem I'm having now is setting different popovers for different parts of the graphic - they're all taking the title and content from the original popover call. Any ideas of a work around for this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: also, if you want to use HTML in the title/content of the popover, make sure you set the `html` flag in the popover options to `true`