# Show certain Raphael shapes on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, click, raphael, dom-selection

There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180963/how-to-call-raphael-methods-on-jquery-objects) on how to call Raphael methods on jQuery objects. It works perfectly. But I need a bit more functionality. I want to show shapes width certain attributes on a button click. In that answer, I could only affect all shapes in the array. How can I filter them? I used that piece of the code:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.each(cottages_array, function(i, c){
        c.animate({fill: '#55bfe1', opacity: 1}, speed_anim_in);
    });
});
```

I have attribute type for my shapes and I want to highlight shapes only with a certain type (type A for example). Inside the cycle, I can fill different types with different colors, but I don't know how to apply any conditions to the click outside of the cycle using jQuery.

```
for (var j = 0; j < obj.cottages.length; j++) {
    var obj_cottages = obj.cottages[j],
    my_path = canvas.path(obj_cottages.coords);
        my_path
            .attr({stroke: "none", fill: cottage_color_start, "fill-opacity": 0.8, opacity: 0, cursor: "pointer"})
            .data('type', obj_cottages.type)

if (obj_cottages.type == 'A') {
    my_path
        .attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#fff", "fill-opacity": 0.8, opacity: 0, cursor: "pointer"})
}
```

I've spent the whole day trying to figure out how to do it and I have no luck at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fionaa/5BYK6/

Comment: Thanks @Neil for replying, I'll create it and reply back to you.

Comment: @Neil here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/Fionaa/5BYK6/

Comment: Thanks @Neil, we create 3d graphic of flats and houses :)

Comment: Sure, I'll do! :) Could you please check my comment on your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I did was to add an id to your buttons, as we need to know which type we want:

```
<button id="A">Type А</button>
<button id="B">Type B</button>
<button id="C">Type C</button>
```

Next I find the id of the button clicked:

```
// get id of button which was clicked
var type = this.id;
```

Then I create a temporary set to hold the cottages which are of that type:

```
// create temporary set
var set = canvas.set();
```

Then in your loop, I find the cottage type that is equal to the clicked type, and add to temporary set

```
// loop all cottages and find the type we want
    c.forEach(function(el){

        // put cottages in the temp set
        if(el.data("type") == type){
            set.push(el);
        }

    });
```

And finally animate this temporary set

```
// animate this set
    set.animate({fill: '#55bfe1', opacity: 1}, speed_anim_in);
```

I have a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/5BYK6/1/

**EDIT**

Ok I have added the following:

```
// fade any previous set
    if(prevSet) {
        prevSet.animate({opacity: 0}, speed_anim_out);
    }

// store current set to remove later
    prevSet = set;
```

Basically we store the previous set we created, and check if there is one that exists in prevSet, we animate to opacity: 0, using your speed_anim_out variable.

See updated fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/5BYK6/2/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! That's brilliant! I had a similar idea, I just didn't know about the sets. The only thing I need to add is a removal of the color from the previously shown set. I mean if I click Type A button and then I click Type B button I still see the highlighted type A objects. I need to check if there is any sets already highlighted and only then to highlight a chosen set. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: I will update this on my lunch break, check back in a couple of hours.